# Green color in Firefox is something else than in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, rgba

I've made a 0x00FF00 (RGB) pixel in MS Paint. For some reason, Mozilla Firefox interprets it as 0x01FF00FF, while Chrome interprets it as 0x00FF00FF. (in RGBA).

Is it just me, is it a bug, or an intended feature?

Comment: What image file format are you using? Does it contain a color profile? JPEG images may be rendered color adjusted if there is a color profile, and PGN images has a specially tricky color correction.

Comment: Post your image example.

Comment: The image is a PNG. I want it to be consistent, and modifiable with Javascript. This is why I chose to not use JPEG.